# Creating video thumbnails with imagekit and opencv

Tags: python, django, opencv, django-imagekit

I have a model named "Post", which is going to refer to images and videos. I added ImageSpecField for thumbnail storage and created a function, that pulls the desired frame from uploaded video. Is there any way to use this function while generating thumbnail? Because right now ImageSpecField can only use FileField as an input.

I have tried creating a new class inheriting from ImageSpecField, but I quickly realized that this is not going to work because this class was instanced only on server start, thus putting this function in constructor of it would not work.

```py
import cv2 as cv
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFit
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField


def video_to_image(source, frame):
    vid_cap = cv.VideoCapture(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + source.__str__())
    vid_cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame)
    success, image = vid_cap.read()
    vid_cap.release()

    return image


class Post(models.Model):
    IMAGE = 'I'
    VIDEO = 'V'
    FILE_TYPES = [
        (IMAGE, 'Image'),
        (VIDEO, 'Video')
    ]

    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=FILE_TYPES)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='post_images')
    thumbnail_frame = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='file',
                                     processors=[ResizeToFit(width=200, height=200)],
                                     format='JPEG',
                                     options={'quality': 60})
```

I want imagekit to generate thumbnail from video, and be able to get it via ImageSpecField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I finally got it. I managed to achieve it by creating another field - thumbnail_source_image and depending on the uploaded file type doing the following:

- for image - setting thumbnail_source_image to the same value as the file field
- for video - generating an image from given millisecond of video, saving it to the same location as the file, and setting it as thumbnail_source_image

I am getting file type using the magic library.

But there is one small problem with this method - for Django to generate file path, we have to call save() method on our model. This forces us to make two requests to the database, instead of one.

## utils.py file:

```
import cv2 as cv


def save_frame_from_video(video_path, millisecond, frame_file_path):
    vidcap = cv.VideoCapture(video_path)

    vidcap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, millisecond)

    success, image = vidcap.read()

    # save image to temp file
    cv.imwrite(frame_file_path, image)

    vidcap.release()
```

## models.py file:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFit
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from .utils import save_frame_from_video


class Post(models.Model):
    image_types = ['image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png']
    video_types = ['video/webm']

    IMAGE = 'I'
    VIDEO = 'V'
    TYPES = [
        (IMAGE, 'Image'),
        (VIDEO, 'Video'),
    ]

    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPES, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='post_files/%Y/%m/%d/')

    thumbnail_millisecond = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    thumbnail_source_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_files/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
    image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='thumbnail_source_image',
                                     processors=[
                                         ResizeToFit(150,
                                                     150,
                                                     mat_color=(230, 230, 230)),
                                     ],
                                     format='JPEG',
                                     options={'quality': 80})

    def _set_type(self):
        # max bytes to read for file type detection
        read_size = 5 * (1024 * 1024)  # 5MB

        # read mime type of file
        from magic import from_buffer
        mime = from_buffer(self.file.read(read_size), mime=True)

        if mime in self.image_types:
            self.type = self.IMAGE
        elif mime in self.video_types:
            self.type = self.VIDEO

    def _set_thumbnail_source_image(self):
        if self.type == self.IMAGE:
            self.thumbnail_source_image = self.file
        elif self.type == self.VIDEO:
            # create thumbnail source file
            image_path = os.path.splitext(self.file.path)[0] + '_thumbnail_src_image.jpg'
            save_frame_from_video(self.file.path, int(self.thumbnail_millisecond), image_path)

            # generate path relative to media root, because this is the version that ImageField accepts
            media_image_path = os.path.relpath(image_path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

            self.thumbnail_source_image = media_image_path

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.type == '':
            self._set_type()
        # if there is no source image
        if not bool(self.thumbnail_source_image):
            # we need to save first, for django to generate path for file in "file" field
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            self._set_thumbnail_source_image()

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```